# MVC 4 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paging, razorengine

From last 2 days i am working on it,but problem is not solved yet.I have tried partial view approach but error is still occurring.

when Layout in view is assign to null.Result is shown with paging.But when we apply  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" then shows following error.
Error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[Matrimony.Models.EditModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Matrimony.Models.LoginModel'.

HomeController

```
public ActionResult SearchGroom(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            UserDetailContext db = new UserDetailContext();

            var grooms = from m in db.PersonalDetails
                    join d in db.HoroscopeDetails on m.PersonalID equals d.PersonalID
                    join b in db.AddressDetails on m.PersonalID equals b.PersonalID
                    join f in db.FamilyDetails on m.PersonalID equals f.PersonalID
                    join ed in db.EducationalDetails on m.PersonalID equals ed.PersonalID
                    join exp in db.Expectations on m.PersonalID equals exp.PersonalID

                    where m.RegID.Contains("S")
                    select new EditModel
                    {
                        RegID = m.RegID,
                        DOB = m.DOB,
                        Height = m.Height,
                        Weight = m.Weight,
                        ParentCity = f.ParentCity,
                        Occupation = ed.Occupation,
                        EducationDetails = ed.EducationDetails,
                        Income = ed.Income,
                        IncomeType = ed.IncomeType,
                    };

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;


               switch (sortOrder)
               {
                   case "name_desc":
                       grooms = grooms.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                       break;
                   case "Date":
                       grooms = grooms.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName);
                       break;
                   case "date_desc":
                       grooms = grooms.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstName);
                       break;
                   default:  // Name ascending 
                       grooms = grooms.OrderBy(s => s.RegID);
                       break;
               }

            int pageSize = 1;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            return View(grooms.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

View Code[Razor]

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Matrimony.Models.EditModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchGroom";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
}

<div class="content_section" style="float: right;width: 670px; margin-right:200px">
    <h2>SearchGroom</h2>
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator" style="width:600px;height:150px;">

        <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Reg. ID</td>
                    <td>Date Of Birth</td>
                    <td>Height</td>
                    <td>Weight</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>Occupation</td>
                    <td>Education</td>
                    <td>Income</td>
                </tr>

            @foreach (Matrimony.Models.EditModel item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td >@item.RegID</td>
                    <td >@item.DOB</td>
                    <td >@item.Height</td>
                    <td >@item.Weight</td>
                    <td >@item.ParentCity</td>
                    <td>@item.Occupation</td>
                    <td >@item.EducationDetails</td>
                    <td >@item.Income &nbsp; @item.IncomeType</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
         <div>
            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

            @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("SearchGroom",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@model Matrimony.Models.LoginModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shehnai Matrimonial Pune</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="pink shop, store template, ecommerce, online shopping, CSS, HTML" />
<meta name="description" content="Pink Shop is a free ecommerce template provided by templatemo.com" />
<link href="../Content/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/table.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/PagedList.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function clearText(field) {
        if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
        else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;
    }
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mootools-1.2.1-core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/slideitmoo-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvents({
        'domready': function () {
            /* thumbnails example , div containers */
            new SlideItMoo({
                overallContainer: 'SlideItMoo_outer',
                elementScrolled: 'SlideItMoo_inner',
                thumbsContainer: 'SlideItMoo_items',
                itemsVisible: 5,
                elemsSlide: 3,
                duration: 200,
                itemsSelector: '.SlideItMoo_element',
                itemWidth: 140,
                showControls: 1
            });
        },

    });
</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..//Content//bjqs.css">      

        <!-- load jQuery and the plugin -->
        <script src="..//Scripts//jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="..//Scripts//bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="templatemo_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_menu">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home")</li>
            @if (Session["Username"] != null )
            {
                 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Details", "EditDetails", "UserDetails")</li>
            }
            else
            {
             <li>@Html.ActionLink("Enroll", "Enroll", "UserDetails")</li>
            }
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Search", "AdvanceSearch", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Grooms", "SearchGroom", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Brides", "SearchBride", "Home")</li>                  
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Response", "Response", "Home")</li>
            <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>       
    </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->

    <div id="templatemo_header_bar">

            <div id="header" style="height:100px"><div class="right"></div>

                <h1>
                    <img src="../Images/templatemo_logo.png" alt="Site Title" />
                  <!--  <span>Online Store Template</span>-->
                </h1>
      </div>

            <div id="search_box">
                <form action="#" method="get">
                    <input type="text" value="Enter matrimonial ID here..." name="q" size="10" id="searchfield" title="searchfield" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" />
                    <input type="submit" name="Search" value="" alt="Search" id="searchbutton" title="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>

    </div> <!-- end of templatemo_header_bar -->

    <div class="cleaner"></div>

    <div id="sidebar"><div class="sidebar_top"></div><div class="sidebar_bottom"></div>

        <div class="sidebar_section">

            @if (Session["Username"] == null || Session["Username"].ToString().Length <1)
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account"))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <input type="submit" name="Log in" value="Log in" alt="Login" id="submit_btn" title="Login" />
                </fieldset>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register","Account") if you don't have an account.
                </p>
            }
            }
            else
            {
                <h1>Welcome...  </h1><b>@Session["Username"]</b>
                <ul class="categories_list">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("My profile", "Showprofile","Home")</li>     
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit profile", "EditForm", "Home")</li> 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change password", "Editpwd", "Home")</li> 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage photo", "Editphoto", "Home")</li> 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete profile", "delete", "Home")</li> 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOut", "Account")</li>      

            </ul>
            }

            <div class="cleaner"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="sidebar_section">

            <h2>Categories</h2>

            <ul class="categories_list">
                <li><a href="#">Success stories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Brides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Why Shahnai matrimony</a></li>   
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Advance Search", "AdvanceSearch","Home")</li>     
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Divorcee Girls", "AdvanceSearch", "Home")</li> 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Divorcee Boyez", "AdvanceSearch", "Home")</li>      

            </ul>
        </div>

      <!--  <div class="sidebar_section">

            <h2>Advance Search</h2>

            <div class="image_wrapper"><a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/7" target="_parent"><img src="../Images/image_01.jpg" alt="product" /></a></div>            
          <div class="discount"><span>25% off</span> | <a href="#">Read more</a></div>

        </div>  -->

    </div> <!-- end of sidebar -->


          <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {       
        $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
            height: 305,
            width: 820,
            responsive: true
        });

    });
          </script>

</div> <!-- end of templatemo_wrapper -->
        <div class="content_section" style="float: right;width: 670px;margin-right:200px">

            <div id="banner-fade">

                <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
                <ul class="bjqs">
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner02.png" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner03.png" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner04.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner05.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner06.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                    <li><img src="..//Images/banner07.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

            </div>
            <!-- End outer wrapper -->




        </div> <!-- end of templatmeo_content -->

 <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">                         

              @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
           <div id="templatemo_footer_wrapper">

    <div id="templatemo_footer">

        <ul class="footer_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/1" target="_parent">CSS Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.flashmo.com/page/1" target="_parent">Flash Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li class="last_menu"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        Copyright © 2048 <a href="#">Your Company Name</a> | 
        <a href="http://www.iwebsitetemplate.com" target="_parent">Website Templates</a> by <a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Free CSS Template</a></div> 
    <!-- end of footer -->

</div>
        </footer>



        <!--RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)    end of footer_wrapper -->      
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Seems like your layout file requires a different type of view model.

Comment: your _Layout view should not be strongly typed to any view it is a master page, transfer the login code in a seperate view

Comment: Currently you are returning List of some type but first _Layout is rendered and there it gets confused because of different models

Comment: after removing login model in layout,it works!!!!! but i want to show login form at left side of each page.until user is login.

Comment: Consider having a partial view that takes in the login model and render the login partial view on your layout page (this login partial will always take the login model).  This should allow you to remove the strongly typed view model from your layout.